# bash script doesn't find mkdir

Tags: bash, shell, osx-mavericks

I've created a simple script to check if a folder exists and if not to create it. The script that follow

```
#!/bin/bash 
PATH=~/Dropbox/Web_Development/
FOLDER=Test

if [ ! -d $PATH$FOLDER ] 
then
    echo $PATH$FOLDER 'not exists'
    /bin/mkdir $PATH$FOLDER
    echo $PATH$FOLDER 'has been created'
fi
```

works only if the mkdir command is preceded by /bin/. Failing in that, bash env output the error message "command cannot be found".

I though this could have been related to the system $PATH variable, but it looks regular (to me) and the output is as following:

```
 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

I'm not sure whether the order with the different bin folders have been listed make any difference, but the /bin one (where the mkdir on my OSX Maverick) seems to reside is there hence I would expect bash to being able to execute this.

In fact, if I call the bash command from terminal, by typing just mkdir bash output the help string to suggest me how the mkdir command should be used. This suggests me that at a first instance bash is able to recognise the $PATH variable.

So what could be the cause? Is there any relation between the opening statement at the top of my .sh - #!/bin/bash - file and the "default" folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, sometimes it is a bad idea to use capital letters for constant variables, because there are some default ones using the same convention. You can see some of the default variables [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FullBashGuide#Parameters) (Scroll to `Special Parameters and Variables` section). So it is better to use long names if you don't want to get any clashes.
Another thing to note is that you're trying to replicate `mkdir -p` functionality, which creates a folder if it does not exist (also it does create all of the parents, which is what you need in most cases)
One more thing - you always have to quote variables, otherwise they get expanded. This may lead to some serious problems. Imagine that

```
fileToRemove='*'
rm $fileToRemove
```

This code will remove all files in the current folder, not a file named `*` as you might expect.
One more thing, you should separate path from a folder with `/`. Like this `"$MY_PATH/$MY_FOLDER"`. That should be done in case you forget to include `/` character in your path variable. It does not hurt to have two slashes, that means that `/home/////////user///` folder is exactly the same `/home/user/` folder.
Sometimes it is tricky to get `~` working, so using `$HOME` is a bit safer and more readable anyway.

So here is your modified script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
MY_PATH="$HOME/Dropbox/Web_Development/"
MY_FOLDER='Test'

mkdir -p "$MY_PATH/$MY_FOLDER"
```

Comment: I'll withdraw my answer, you read the rest of the script and understood the meaning of "PATH" for the OP ^^. +1

Comment: It seems the previous answer for some reason has gone, so please don't remove this one. Thanks for your input anyway. That said I've a challenge: my script will be run from a third part system (Vagrant) that runs the script as a root user. Therefore by using $HOME, this  will correspond to Root's home and not mine. Is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: There is no easy way. You can try this ``IFS=: read -r _ _ _ _ _ home _ <<< "$(getent passwd "$SUDO_USER")"; echo "$home"`` to place user's home to ``$home`` variable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your script sets `PATH` to a single directory, and that single directory does not contain a program called `mkdir`.

- Do not use `PATH` as the name of a variable (use it to list the directories to be searched for commands).
- Do learn the list of [standard environment variable names](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) and those specific to the shell you use (e.g. [`bash` shell variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Variables)).  Or use a simple heuristic: reserved names are in upper-case, so use lower-case names for variables local to a script.  (Most environment variables are in upper-case — standard or not standard.)

And you can simply ensure that the directory exists by using:

```
mkdir -p ~/Dropbox/Web_Development
```

If it already exists, no harm is done. If it does not exist, it is created, and any other directories needed on the path to the directory (eg `~/Dropbox`) is also created if that is missing.